# In Postgres, how would I convert the following text to a date?

Tags: postgresql

In the following expression

```
"DATETIME"::date || ' 23:59:59.000'
```

I'm converting a DATETIME field to a pure date. The string concatenation changes the value to the very end of the day. I would now like to insert this value back into another DATETIME field but I am unsure how to convert from text back to DATETIME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression should work.

```
("DATETIME"::date || ' 23:59:59.000')::timestamp
```

Depending on your application, you might need to consider [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second). The 59th second isn't invariably the last second before the next date.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support leap seconds anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the type of the DATETIME field is something like TIMESTAMP. If so, just cast the whole string back to a TIMESTAMP:

```
("DATETIME"::date || ' 23:59:59.00')::timestamp
```